# Problems working with ormlite using IntelliJ on Mac OSX

Tags: android, intellij-idea, ormlite

I am developing an Android application with a sqlite database in an Ubuntu loaded notebook on Intellij IDEA and using database mapping using ormlite. I installed `ormlite-android-4.23.jar`, `ormlite-core-4-1.31.jar`, and `ormlite-4.23.jar` in libs directory of the project folder.  I was not sure which version is used here.  The application was running and I tried to use my Macbook to proceed with my app development. I am new to Macbook. It is loaded with  Mac OS X version 10.5.8. The app is not running.

The following are indicated in red by Intellij and its message is:

```
cannot resolve
```

j256 in `import com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteBaseActivity`, and other places related ormlite.

I am new to developing this kind of applications and can anybody help me? I noted in a similar question the answer was downloading ormlite version 4.20. I need to know exactly the name of file and where should be saved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you need 2 files:

- `ormlite-core-4.33.jar`
- `ormlite-android-4.33.jar`

Place these files in any directory of your project (while `libs` is designed for native .so libraries, many developers use it for jar libraries so you can use it). Then configure a library in IntelliJ IDEA and [add it to the dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) of your module.

Comment: I installed the latest version of ormlite in the MacBook. The above problem is solved. Thanks again for the answer. I am still having another ormlite related problem in the MacBook which was not an issue in Ubuntu. In the following piece of code of the same application, getFeatureIntegerDao(); is highlighted in red in Intellij IDEA. Message is "Cannot resolve the method". Feature is a class mapping the sqlite table features of a sqlite database having four tables.

Dao<Feature, Integer> featureIntegerDao = getHelper().getFeatureIntegerDao();

Comment: You should submit another question with more details and a sample project.

Answer (score 0):

You also can add it to your dependencies:

```
compile group: 'com.j256.ormlite', name: 'ormlite-core', version: '4.33'
compile group: 'com.j256.ormlite', name: 'ormlite-android', version: '4.33'
```