# ORMLite 'Cannot resolve method' in IntelliJ IDEA 13 Mac OSX (using Lombok)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, ormlite, lombok

First I should say that I already tried [Problems working with ormlite using IntelliJ on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107947/problems-working-with-ormlite-using-intellij-on-mac-osx) to solve the problem. Unfortunately, even after configuring my environment with the ORMLite library ormlite-android-4.48 and ormlite-core-4.48, whenever I try to run the android application it still shows me a list of about 100 instances where a method cannot be resolved. Each of these instances is whenever I am requesting a method that ORMLite is supposed to handle. The only other thing I can think of is that using Lombok could be screwing things up? Here is a screenshot of the piece of code. The getters with red show up 98 more times in other places. [image]

Really the question is, why can IntelliJ not find the method? It might be something incredibly obvious but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(may or mayn't help, but too long for a comment)

> Each of these instances is whenever I am requesting a method that ORMLite is supposed to handle.

It looks more like your problem are methods Lombok should generate, but doesn't. Try this

```
import lombok.Getter;

public class FancyClass {
    @Getter private int x;
    void q() {
        return getX();
    }
}
```

If it doesn't compile, then your problem is purely Lombok-related. Google out how to install it properly on IntelliJ / Mac.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! You're right it definitely has to do with Lombok.